# Phonenumber from Google Contacts API 3

Tags: javascript, contacts, google-apps

I'm developing and application in javascript. I need to get my gmail contacts and their phone numbers.

I have tried the "Sample - Oauth Contacts" from https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples.html and it works, but it does not retrieve the phonenumber.

According to the documentation in https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/ it should retrieve a tag like this:

```
<gd:phoneNumber rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#home'
        primary='true'>
      456
 </gd:phoneNumber>
```

but it does not appear. It only gets the name (title), ID, and email.

Do you know if I am missing something? Is there any restriction on using this API from a google extension?

Thanks in advance!!